# Python pd.read_excel Unsupported format, or corrupt file

Tags: python, xls

Can someone tell me why do I receive this error message when I run my data pipeline?
My writer script used python with

```
df = pd.read_excel(xls_file, sheet, header=None)
```

The error message was:

```
Message: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b{"error"
```

I am trying to understand what's going on with the data so the script would not read it.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Based on

> Expected BOF record; found b{"error"

it looks like what you expect to be an XLS file is actually a JSON file that represents some sort of error. You can verify my hunch by opening that file in a text editor.

I suspect an earlier part of your data pipeline doesn't e.g. check whether a remote server returns an error (e.g. `resp.raise_for_status()` in Requests), so you end up dumping some arbitrary data into the file.